# Is Local Search score calculation 10 /sec normal?

Tags: performance, optaplanner, calculation

I am working in a problem with a 16 core computer. Multithreading in set to auto.

The number of planning entities(nullable) is 137760. I am implementing valueRangeProvider so the possible number of planning values for each one of them ranges from 2 to 4.

I have seen in the docs that usually score calculation speed is above 1k score/s. Even with CH (with partitioning each 17k entities), the speed is below this numbers.

The things is I've tried to check for the speed with different rules sintaxis. The rule that lowers speed the most is a medium constraint that I've added in order for the planning entity not to be null (for my problem, I am trying to maxmize the number of assigned planning entities but some of them Will have to be null due to harder constraints).

My question is if the speed is normal considering the problem scale and if any of you might have any ideas to how I can face this.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not.

Find out which of your constraint is the bottleneck. In your ConstraintProvider or scoreDRL, comment them out one by one, and do a 30 second run from the solution after the CH (so LS is run directly) and then look at the log how it is impacted by that. That's a good way to figure out the slow constraints.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried what you said but score calculation speed is 0/s for 30s for any of the rules. There are differences in CH though. Then I tried again for a 1min LS run. Best speed I got for LS was 4/sec (2k/s for CH).

Comment: I tried different rule combinations in case there were two rules that needed to be rewritten and indeed, that was the case. Still, best score calculation speed I got was 120 score/s

Comment: I was wondering what makes the score calculation so different between construction heuristics and Local Search. I mean in swapping moves the calculated score implies calculating "twice". But why is my LS speed more than 10 times slower than for CH?

Comment: CH starts with an unitialized solution, so nothing assigned. When 2 entities are assigned, it's much easier to calculate the score of assigning a 3th then when 2000 entities are assigned. For example for conflict detection, it needs far more comparisons.